# How to get the actual COM port number with SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty

Tags: c++, serial-port

I'm trying to get a list of available COM ports with the "Windows 2000"-method explained here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/setupdi.aspx

My current code: http://pastebin.ca/1977670
This is what I get:

```
\\?\ftdibus#vid_0403+pid_6001+ftf479xra#0000#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}
USB Serial Port (COM13)
USB Serial Port

\\?\hdaudio#func_02&ven_11c1&dev_1040&subsys_11c10001&rev_1002#4&ddab605&0&0101#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}
Agere Systems HDA Modem
Agere Systems HDA Modem
```

I looked through the different options of SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty, but I can't find the right one to get the actual COM port number. (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551967(VS.85).aspx)

I *could* look for COMXXX in the friendly name (via regex or whatever..), but I don't think that this would be the correct solution...

Comment: Please note that you don't usually need or want the COM port number, since `CreateFile` works just fine if given a device interface path.  You only need the COM port number when dealing with legacy software (and it's much more convenient to type).  Please understand, though, that writing COM port code that doesn't accept real device paths is comparable to writing a file I/O library that can't deal with long file names and expects you to provide the 8.3 short name.

Comment: I used this for displaying a dropdown list for the user to select one of the COM ports that will be used in the application, not for actually using the COM port.

Comment: Then just use the friendly name.  There's no need to extract the COM port number from it, and the other information (is it USB?  Bluetooth?) is usually more valuable than the number, so you *shouldn't* extract the COM port number.

Comment: I didn't work on the project for some time, but as I remember I displayed the friendly name and the COM port in braces behind that. If I remember correctly it had something to do with the fact that configuring serial ports for Bluetooth only showed the assigned COM port and so it was quite helpful to see the actual COM port number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SetupDiOpenDevRegKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff552079.aspx) to open the device's registry and query the "PortName" value; this will give you back something like "COM4".  There are a few more [ways to query COM ports](http://www.naughter.com/enumser.html).

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll try to finish my function with SetupDiOpenDevRegKey as an exercise... the library you mentioned looks really great for what I'm trying to accomplish.